# Finding which given functions are equal to each others

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

I have about 50 piece functions (generally trigonometric functions).
I want to find out which ones are equal to each other after some simplifications such as `FullSimplify`,`TrigReduce`, `ExpToTrig` etc.

For a simple example;

```
        v[1] = Tan[x]
    v[2] = Sin[x]/Cos[x]
    v[3] = 1/Cos[x] + (Sin[x] - 1)/Cos[x] 
    v[4] = 1/Sin[x] + (Cos[x] - 1)/Sin[x] 
    v[5] = Cot[x]
    v[6] = (I (E^(-I x) - E^(I x)))/(E^(-I x) + E^(I x))
v[7] = -((I (E^(-I x) + E^(I x)))/(E^(-I x) - E^(I x)))
```

I want to reach the result `v[1]= v[2]=v[6]` and `v[4]=v[5]=v[7]` instead of `True` or `False`.

I can delete the duplicates using `Table[v[i], {i, 1, 7}] // ExpToTrig // TrigReduce // DeleteDuplicates`. But I can' t show which one are equal. It's very tedious to test one by one as follows: (for many functions)

```
TrueQ[v[1] == v[3] // TrigReduce]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another possibility is to use `Reduce`

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The above table gives the conditions for equality.

Generated using:

```
ClearAll[x];
v = {Tan[x], Sin[x]/Cos[x], 1/Cos[x] + (Sin[x] - 1)/Cos[x],
   1/Sin[x] + (Cos[x] - 1)/Sin[x], 
   Cot[x], (I (E^(-I x) - E^(I x)))/(E^(-I x) + E^(I x)),
   -((I (E^(-I x) + E^(I x)))/(E^(-I x) - E^(I x)))};

res = Last@
  Reap@Do[Do[
     Sow@{"v(" <> ToString@m <> ") == v(" <> ToString@n <> ")", 
       Reduce[v[[m]] == v[[n]], x]}, {n, m + 1, Length@v}], {m, 1, 
     Length@v}]

Grid[Flatten[res, 1], Frame -> All]
```

You could modify the `Reduce` call above if you want to say add `Reals` for example. You can also add a range on `x` in the Reduce call to restrict the range.

It shows that `v1=v2=v3` and `v4=v5` with no conditions.

Answer (score 10):

#### GroupBy

```
GroupBy[Range[7], FullSimplify @* v]
```

or

```
GroupBy[Range[7], ExpToTrig @* v]
```

> ```
> <|Tan[x] -> {1, 2, 3, 6}, Cot[x] -> {4, 5, 7}|>
> ```

```
Values @ GroupBy[Range[7], FullSimplify @*v, Apply[Equal] @* Map[Inactive[v]]]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
Equal @@@ Values @ GroupBy[Range @ 7, FullSimplify @* v, Map[Defer @ v]]
```

[image]

#### Gather/ GatherBy

```
Gather[Range @ 7, PossibleZeroQ[v @ # - v @ #2] &]
```

or

```
GatherBy[Range @ 7, FullSimplify @* v]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3, 6}, {4, 5, 7}}
> ```

Answer (score 9):

I'd check equivalences using `PossibleZeroQ`. Then the equivalence classes can be bundled using some `Graph` functionality.

Set up the functions list.

```
vv = {Tan[x],
   Sin[x]/Cos[x],
   1/Cos[x] + (Sin[x] - 1)/Cos[x],
   1/Sin[x] + (Cos[x] - 1)/Sin[x],
   Cot[x],
   (I (E^(-I x) - E^(I x)))/(E^(-I x) + E^(I x)),
   -((I (E^(-I x) + E^(I x)))/(E^(-I x) - E^(I x)))};
len = Length[vv];
```

Make lists of the pairs and the pair differences.

```
pairs = Subsets[Range[len], {2}];
diffs = Apply[Subtract, Subsets[vv, {2}], {1}];
```

Find which pairs are equivalent.

```
equivs = Pick[pairs, Map[PossibleZeroQ, diffs]]

(* Out[741]= {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 6}, {2, 3},
{2, 6}, {3, 6}, {4, 5}, {4, 7}, {5, 7}} *)
```

Now create lists of equivelent elements.

```
gg = Graph[Range[len], equivs];
ConnectedComponents[gg]

(* Out[743]= {{1, 2, 3, 6}, {4, 5, 7}} *)
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to `Hold` or `HoldForm` the `v[i]` or they will evaluate to their defined function expressions.

```
Equal @@@ 
 Gather[Table[With[{i = i}, HoldForm@v[i]], {i, 1, 7}], 
  TrueQ@Simplify[ReleaseHold[#1 - #2] == 0] &]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Using [`RelationGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RelationGraph.html) + [`ConnectedComponents`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConnectedComponents.html) as a variation on Daniel's approach:

```
rg = RelationGraph[FullSimplify[v @ # == v @ #2 && # =!= #2] &, Range @ 7, 
       VertexLabels -> {i_ :> Defer[v][i]}]

Show[rg, PlotLabel -> Style[Equal @@@ Map[Defer[v]] /@ ConnectedComponents @ rg, 16]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
DeleteDuplicates@ExpToTrig@Table[v[i], {i, 1, 7}]
(*{Tan[x], Cot[x]}*)
```

Also:

```
Reduce[v[1] === v[2] === ExpToTrig[v[6]]]
(*True*)
Reduce[v[4] === v[5] === ExpToTrig[v[7]]]
(*False*)
```

Comment: I want to reach the result `v[1]= v[2]=v[6]` and `v[4]=v[5]=v[7]` instead of `(*{Tan[x], Cot[x]}*)` or `True` or `False`.